# updating alarm from pending intent in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am working on an Alarm Clock project and i want to edit my already set Alarm.
when I edit alarm then alarm time is updated but values that I send by using `putExtra()` are not changing. I am using `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` flag.

But when I set flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` all `putExtra()` values are also change but now problem is that, when i click on stop button and `finish()` the current activity it calls again.

means when I go to finish the activity it calls again on button click while I am finishing current activity.
please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

My prefered way to update a PendingIntent in AlarmManager is to Cancel it and re-set it
do not forget to cancel : 

1) `AlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)` with a pendingIntent that match your pending intent (same class , same action ... but do not care about extra see [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html))
2) `pendingIntent.cancel();` 
3) `pendingIntent = new PendingIntent()` ... and do other settings
4) `AlarmManager.set(...` to provide new PendingIntent

Comment: In case of calendar events setting alarm, If we use a  local variable and not static, we can assign various time for various events. But it seems that you have shown static pendingIntent example

Comment: Is REALLY this is the only way to update the alarm? WORKED FOR ME.

Answer (score 2):

Each alarm has its unique identifier, if you want to update an alarm, you can create a new one with the same UNIQUE_ID.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, 0);
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481169/3224729)