# BroadcastReceiver for setting an Alarm in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Is there a way to to receive a broadcast(System broadcast,may be) in android as soon as user of the phone sets an Alarm?

I googled this and most of the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556670/how-to-check-if-alarmmanager-already-has-an-alarm-set) on stackoveflow seems to be around how to check if alarm is already set using `AlarmManager` class and how this [can or cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930034/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-an-alarm-is-already-set) be done etc.

I guess my requirement is little different, because I want to register a `BroadcastReciver` through my app, which should be notified as soon as user sets an Alarm. Even if user sets multiple alarm, my app should be notified for each alarm, set by the user.

I am also ok for any other way beside `BroadcastReciver` too for this, if one exist in Android.

**Update**: I tried `android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` with my BroadcastReceiver after the suggestion from **PeterChaula** and it worked. But that this `ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` was introduced in API Level 21 and my app needs to support `minSdkVersion` of 14 and above.

Comment: this broadcast could be useful to you - `android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` but it's only 21+

Comment: @PeterChaula let me quickly try with this broadcast. but ya, my app's minSdkVersion is 14. So I need another solution for sure...

Comment: @PeterChaula I tried the `android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED` and it worked. But as I stated earlier I need the solution for minSdkVersion of 14 and above.

Comment: You could maybe try observing `content://com.android.deskclock/alarm` but it's a bit inconsistent across manufacturers as some replace the default clock app with their own.